# excel vba copy row and paste to new sheet as pastevalue

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy data from sheet "summary" row A44 (fixed row with dynamic data with formula) to sheet18 (row A3), A1 and A2 are header; i have below vba code and manage to do so. I would like to copy and paste the data as value (like `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False`), so that the data will convert to absolute number, anyone how to edit the code?

```
Sub COPY_SUMMARY2COPYDATA()

    Set des = Sheet18.Range("a1")

    With Worksheets("SUMMARY")
        .Rows(Range("A44").Row).Copy
        des.Range("A3").Insert Shift:=xlUp
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really want to insert the results, or is there a blank cell / cells waiting in Sheet18 to receive the data? It's hard to tell from your example code.

Comment: sorry if my explanation is not clear. i have dynamic data need to copy to sheet18, so new result will add them from row3 onwards, eg. row3, row4,row5.....sheet18 is a blank sheet except first two rows are header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
Sub COPY_SUMMARY2COPYDATA()    

    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Sheet18.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(XlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets("SUMMARY").Rows("44").Copy         
    Sheet18.Rows(LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Hope this help

Comment: hi thanks, it's working, but i have dynamic data, how can i insert another new row and add them below the last one copied in row 4,5,6....

Comment: hi, yes, it's working now perfectly, i have learnt new things today, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To find the first blank cell in column A look from the bottom up and offset down one row.

Use a direct value transfer with .Value2 to pass over *'the data will convert to absolute number'*. This will discard regional currency and date conventions as well as formulas in favor of the raw underlying value.

```
with Worksheets("SUMMARY")
    with intersect(.usedrange, .rows(44).cells)
        Sheet18.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(1, 0).resize(.rows.count, .columns.count) = .value2
    end with
end with
```

Comment: HI sorry i am not really understand on value2? can u share more detail?

Comment: Can you lookup .Value2 on MSDN? I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2(v=office.15).aspx) in 5 seconds. You stated you wanted the *'absolute number'*; if you want to keep date and/or currency information, change to `.Value` or format the cells after the value transfer.